# Create a spectrogram in python (without drawing)

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, fft, spectrogram

I'm trying to create a spectrogram object for audio analysis.

I'm using [Snack Library](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/man/snack2.2/python-man.html). This library, create the spectrogram as a canvas object but I
should use the spectrogram as a numerical object (every 10 ms I should extract the vector of frequencies).

This is the code of Snack Library:

```
c = tkSnack.SnackCanvas(root, height=400)
c.pack()
c.create_waveform(0, 0, sound=mysound, height=100, zerolevel=1)
c.create_spectrogram(0, 150, sound=mysound, height=200)
```

I'm looking for tutorials online but I only found ways to draw the spectrogram.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a reason to think Snack will do this?  I haven't used the library for years, but this is primarily because one runs into simple limitations like this very quickly.

Comment: Ok... do you know another (good) library for audio analysis in python?

Comment: I don't know of a good library specifically designed for only audio analysis.  Personally, I just use the tools available in the standard packages like matplotlib (which has a reasonable spectrogram), numpy, scipy, etc.

Comment: OK.  I wrote it up as an answer so I could provide more specific links, etc.  Personally, I've found this more generalized approach very useful.

Comment: What do you mean with "every 10 ms I should extract the vector of frequencies"? A 10ms hop for a data blockenizer or a 10ms rate for drawing like [this time and spectra animated plot example](https://github.com/danilobellini/audiolazy/blob/c554181e5780e0203877ce78f15e20fcb3e66209/examples/animated_plot.py) in [AudioLazy](https://github.com/danilobellini/audiolazy), my DSP package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For audio analysis I just use a combination of the generalized data analysis tools.  Here are the tools I use for audio:

**reading and writing .wav files**:
[Python wave module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html), and [scipy.io.wave](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html)
These work for most .wav files, but not the very unusual formats

**FFTs**:
numpy [rfft](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html) and friends ([rfftfreq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfftfreq.html#numpy.fft.rfftfreq) is particularly useful with rfft)

**spectrograms and more general graphs**:
[matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_summary.html) and, in particular matplotlib's [specgram](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.specgram)